# How do I deny the access to the static files of the corresponding course which is not purchased by the user? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm working on an Udemy clone. Currently I'm working on the functionality of showing the details of course to the people who didn't purchase the course and showing the details, lessons and videos to the people who purchase the course and have access to it. I have some sort of solution for that but I don't think it's the right one.

My solution is storing people who has access inside a Course's foreign key field, so using that foreign key lookup on a currently logged in user I check whether a user's id is listed in that list of people who own the course. The problem of that approach is that if people who didn't purchase a course have a precise link to the video which is a part of the course, they can just type it in the searching bar and see the video, that's because this video is a media file or a static file. Here's the code that I wrote for that:

Models code:

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='courses')
    students = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='courses', blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Section(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sections')
    ...

class Lesson(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, db_index=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lessons")

    video = models.FileField(upload_to=directory_for_images, blank=True, max_length=500)
    ...
```

And here's a views code that I wrote:

```
def courseConditionalView(request, pk):
    course = models.Course.objects.get(pk = pk)
    current_user = request.user
    course_bought = False
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        course_bought = bool(current_user.courses.filter(pk = pk))

    if course_bought:
        return redirect(reverse('course_details_study', kwargs={'pk': str(pk)}))
    else:
        return render(request, 'courses/course_detail.html', {'course': course})

def studyView(request, pk):
    course = models.Course.objects.get(pk = pk)
    current_user = request.user
    course_bought = False
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        course_bought = bool(current_user.courses.filter(pk = pk))

    if course_bought:
        return render(request, 'courses/course_detail_study.html', {'course': course})
    else:
        return redirect(reverse(courseConditionalView, kwargs={'pk': str(pk)}))
```

So I wrote two views the one which is `studyView` is for people who purchased the course and the `courseConditionalView` is for people who didn't purchase it

The question is how do I prevent the static files and media files from being accessed by the people who don't own the course?

Or if this is a completely wrong approach how do I do this the right way, my guess is that doing it through permissions would be a much better approach but I don't know whether it's possible to dynamically create permissions at the time when courses are created and dynamically assign them to users at the time when they purchase the course.

Comment: I do not know about your setup, but most likely the static files are not served by "django" but are served by your server directly from disc. Do you use nginx, apache ...? Basically you have to tell that instance which serves your static files your way of authentication. I do not know how to do that though. I am struggling with it for nginx ever since.

Comment: @Tarquinius yes, I'm serving my static files directly from my computer and not from a nginx or apache, so you mean that you can set some rules for the nginx server, for example, so that static files won't be accessible by users and only accessible by the server during rendering of the page, right? I actually never used any of those for development but I've heard of them, so I will be looking them up then, to come up with the solution